# Move number down if number is missing mysql

Tags: php, mysql, numbers

I've got a database with question numbers between 1 and 21 all with answers / values etc. 
But I want to be able to delete for example question 7.
And if I delete that question that is between other numbers that the question numbers will automatically change from 1-21 to 1-20 instead of 1-6, 8-21.
Is this possible? I tried searching on the web but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

With kind regards,

How do I make this shorter? I know it can be done with innerjoin but I dont know how to correctly use it because the explanations are unclear to me..

```
`$sql = "DELETE FROM insertquestion 
WHERE nummer='".$questionNumber."'"; 

$deleteFromQuestion = $db->prepare($sql); 
$deleteFromQuestion->execute(); 
$updateSql = "UPDATE insertquestion SET nummer = nummer - 1 WHERE nummer >= '".$questionNumber."'"; 

$updateSql = $db->prepare($updateSql); 
$updateSql->execute();`
```

and that another time but then with another table (`vraag`)

Comment: `update thetable set qnum = qnum - 1 where qnum > 7` use this query in your code or make a trigger after delete

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would like to do this maintenance on database level? When you output the questions in your php code, you can apply any kind of numbering you want.

Comment: where you need this facility.....

Comment: Thank you @splash58 I'm gonna try that out after my break and comment how it worked out. and just for the ease shadow because I'm not deleting the question but IF i want to delete the question I'd have to adjust the numbering everytime

Comment: You should add a trigger `after delete` in which you can update all question numbers again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Triggers to do this operation ref:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

or use a update query to set the values (however this method is costly, if tthe number of rows is great in number)

```
Update table set q_no=q_no-1 where q_no> 5 //(if you delete a question with number 5)
```

Comment: How do I make this shorter? I know it can be done with innerjoin but I dont know how to correctly use it because the explanations are unclear to me..

`$sql = "DELETE FROM insertquestion
WHERE nummer='".$questionNumber."'";
$deleteFromQuestion = $db->prepare($sql);
$deleteFromQuestion->execute();

$updateSql = "UPDATE insertquestion SET nummer = nummer - 1 WHERE nummer >= '".$questionNumber."'";
$updateSql = $db->prepare($updateSql);
$updateSql->execute();`

and that another time but then with the table `vraag`

Comment: As the number of rows in your table is lesser it shouldn't be a problem. There will be problems only when the number of rows relatively more than a million, and the update is more frequent. frequent in the sence is more than a thousand requests with in a second @Theekopje

Comment: The Method you are using is actually better. However i would add both the queries inside a trasaction. @Theekopje

Comment: How do you mean? I meant how can I make the code shorter instead of copy paste and change the name. I'm intrigued how to do that. I know that it can be done with innerjoin but I don't understand the explanation correctly

Comment: Thank you Andrews I've got it like this now and it works perfectly!

`$db->beginTransaction();
                $db->exec("DELETE FROM insertquestion WHERE nummer='".$questionNumber."'");
                $db->exec("UPDATE insertquestion SET nummer = nummer - 1 WHERE nummer >= '".$questionNumber."'");
                $db->commit();` Thank you so much. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There may be many ways for this requirement. One of them is you can achieve it by trigger. Write an after delete trigger which will update all question numbers of the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblquestion_delete AFTER DELETE on tblquestion
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblquestion
    SET qno = qno - 1
    WHERE qno > old.qno;
END
```

Another way is simply you can write this query immediately after delete query.

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM insertquestion WHERE number='".$questionNumber."' ;
 UPDATE tblquestion SET number = number - 1 WHERE number > '".$questionNumber."' ; ";
```

Comment: Should I add $sql infront of UPDATE aswell? Or would it work like that?